# Regex expression for repeated pattern

Tags: regex

I need to identify pattern like this in a text file:

> 123/12 (6/26/2020) 134/01 0/0 1/0 134/67 345/89

`digit/digit` group is repeated 7 times with the first one has date in it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far that you can show? Start simple: what is the regex for a "digit/digit" pattern? What's the regex for matching the previous pattern a specified number of times? Etc.

Comment: (\d/\d)*{7}  I am using python, It does work but not showing 7 matching. Also I am not sure about how to incorporate date in first matching but not in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `regex` instead of `re` and try something along the lines of:

```
^(\d+\/\d+) \((?1)\/\d+\)(?: (?1)){5}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8clnc/3)

I'm not sure about the context you are planning to use it in so you might be interested in word-boundaries too.

---

Update:

Based on your comment, it looks like you need to try implement something like:

```
import regex
lst = ['123/12 (6/26/2020) 134/01 0/0 1/0 134/67 345/89', 'blabla', '123/12 (11/2/2019) 112/11 3/2 1/5 112/987 23/1']
new_lst = [x for x in lst if regex.match(r'^(\d+\/\d+) \((?1)\/\d+\)(?: (?1)){5}$', x)]
print(new_lst)
```

Gets you:

```
['123/12 (6/26/2020) 134/01 0/0 1/0 134/67 345/89', '123/12 (11/2/2019) 112/11 3/2 1/5 112/987 23/1']
```

Comment: I have a list of text and I need to find line with such patterns. How would you compile such an expression in python if I don't use re. Sorry I have not work too much with regex in python.

Comment: Great. Thanks.It worked.